# Не могу понять почему не отображаются картинки в Статичном Ленде

Tags: html, css, github-pages

Всем привет.

Делал учебный ленд чисто на HTML+CSS в VSC предпросмотре в расширении Live Server все картинки размещенны корректно и вроде в коде нету каких то особых косяков, но при заливке на Git Pages сайт не отображает не одной из них. Даже нету бека в интро теге..

1. фото вид проекта на Live Server
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. вид проекта на Github Pages
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Пример строения Блока с картинкой
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай оставлю ссылку
на репоз: https://github.com/Makayd44/AB-3
на GithubPages:https://makayd44.github.io/AB-3/

Буду благодарен любой помощи и подсказке. Хорошего всем вечера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для картинок вы используете абсолютные пути, поэтому итоговый путь получается следующий:

https://makayd44.github.io/assets/works/4.jpg

Но при этом ссылка на ваш сайт выглядит так:

https://makayd44.github.io/AB-3

Поменяйте абсолютные пути на относительные, т.е в src для картинок уберите первый слеш '/'.

Это нужно для того, чтобы не искать картинки в корневой директории, а искать их в директории проекта, т.е в `AB-3/`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Используйте абсолютный путь URL к каждой картинке

Например, `https://makayd44.github.io/assets/services/2.png`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не может найти файлы)

Comment: Ссылка в вашем ответе отдает 404, т.к картинки лежат в директории `AB-3/assets`

Comment: Спасибо большое